# How can I call a C program from a shell script?

Tags: c, bash

I need  to demonize a client socket in C, and I really don't have any knowledge about how to write a bash script but I need it in my project, so I have that example:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
start)
rm -f /var/run/alarm.pid
echo "$$" >> /var/run/alarm.pid
while true
do
cd /usr/local/
//client program socket here
perl socket.pl 

sleep 11 
done
;;
stop)

kill -9 $(cat /var/run/alarm.pid)
rm -f /var/run/alarm.pid
echo stop
exit 0

;;
esac
exit 0
```

I don't know where to put my .c file (code client) in that script, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have **no** idea what this is about. Do you expect `bash` to execute C code? :o

Comment: Compile the c code to an executable and call that executable from your script. If you need to, put the absolute path to your executable.

Comment: @FelixPalmen the client receive data from the server so yes i want bash to execute my c socket code to get data every 11 seconds,

Comment: @matt how can i call the executable from that script

Comment: @mery, the same way you call `perl` -- the Perl interpreter itself is a compiled C program -- or the same way you run `rm` or `cat` (which likewise executables created by compiling C code). Executable files, as created by the C compiler (+linker) are just commands -- you use the command's name to run it, fully-qualifying that name if it isn't in your PATH.

Comment: ...so, you use your compiler (like `gcc`) to create an executable, then put the name of the executable in your script as a command.

Comment: Call it like you call any other executable. `chmod` it to be executable if necessary. Then write its name or path if needed in the script. But shell (bash) cannot run a .c file (the source code!) directly. If the .c file changes (I doubt that, but who knows) recompile it in your script prior calling it. If you need to direct input or output from or to the executable to or from your script consider using pipes.

Comment: That said, *this is the wrong way to go about daemonizing a program in general*. Use your operating system's process supervision mechanism, be that [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) (on older Debian/Ubuntu) or [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) (on current Fedora/Debian/Ubuntu/Arch/others) or [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) (on MacOS) or whatever else.

Comment: @mery, ...since the intended use case is this frequent of a polling schedule, I'd also suggest having your C program itself support sleeping and rerunning instead of requiring it to be continuously restarted. `fork()`ing and `exec()`ing a new instance of a program has some overhead, and means you can't reuse any other resources such as log handles you might have set up.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for you replies, but i have to do it that way as i'm told, so instead of _perl_  i write the relative name of my executable?

Comment: Or the absolute path to that executable, as you choose.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i'm writing this script in a script.sh folder and then i will make it executable with _chmod_ .. is it the right way ? i'm sorry i'm just a begginer ..

Comment: This script appears to be patterned after an old SysV-style init script. Not all operating systems still support them at all (and I'm firmly of the belief that they weren't a good idea to begin with), but correct installation of those is typically in a location like `/etc/rc.d/init.d`; it varies with the details of your specific operating system. Hopefully whoever's instructing you to do it this way will be able to provide locally-appropriate details.